# Concatenate 2 dates into string with no forward slash

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two date columns I want to combine into 1 column (as a key for another process)

For example:

```
+------------+------------+
|  Column 1  |  Column 2  |
+------------+------------+
| 01/01/2020 | 01/30/2020 |
+------------+------------+
```

New column = Query or calculated field (no forward slashes, only 1 hyphen):

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+
|  Column 1  |  Column 2  |   Unique Column   |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
| 01/01/2020 | 01/30/2020 | 01012020-01302020 |
+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Each record could have a unique date in column 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a loooooong time since I worked with Access but if they are Date type columns I believe it'd be something similar to this.

```
Format ([Column1], "mmddyyyy") & "-" & Format ([Column2], "mmddyyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update mytable set
newCol = replace(col1, '/', '') & '-' & replace(col2, '/', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If each record **must** have a unique combination of`Column1`and`Column2`[create a multiple-field index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0A8E2AA6-735C-4C3A-9DDA-38C6C4F1A0CE) with property`Unique`or`Primary`

> To create a multiple-field index for a table, you include a row for each field in the index and include the index name only in the first row. Access treats all rows as part of the same index until it comes to a row containing another index name. To insert a row, right-click the location where you want to insert a row, and then click Insert Rows on the shortcut menu.
>
> 1. In the Navigation Pane, right-click the name of the table that you want to create the index in, and then click Design View on the shortcut menu.
> 2. On the Design tab, in the Show/Hide group, click Indexes.
>
>    The Indexes window appears. Resize the window so that some blank rows appear and the index properties are shown.
> 3. In the Index Name column, in the first blank row, type a name for the index. You can name the index after one of the index fields, or use another name.
> 4. In the Field Name column, click the arrow and then click the first field that you want to use for the index.
> 5. In the next row, leave the Index Name column blank, and then, in the Field Name column, click the second field for the index. Repeat this step until you select all the fields that you want to include in the index.
> 6. To change the sort order of the field's values, in the Sort Order column of the Indexes window, click Ascending or Descending. The default sort order is Ascending.
> 7. In the Indexes window, under Index Properties, set the index properties for the row in the Index Name column that contains the name of the index. Set the properties according to the following table.
>
>    Primary -> If Yes, the index is the primary key.
>      Unique -> If Yes, every value in the index must be unique.
>      Ignore Nulls -> If Yes, records with a Null value in the indexed fields are excluded from the index.
> 8. To save your changes, click Save on the Quick Access Toolbar or press CTRL + S.
> 9. Close the Indexes window.